# Preview orientation in landscape mode is rotated clockwise with Camera2 api's

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have written a Camera application using Camera2 api's.
But when I open the app in landscape mode the object in the preview looks 90 degree rotated clockwise.

But I don't see the same issue in Potrait mode.

What is causing this issue in landscape mode?

This is the Screen rotation code:

```
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
```

Comment: What are you using for your camera preview View? A SurfaceView, a TextureView or something else?

Comment: I would be interested in your solution as well, if you found any.

Comment: @EddyTalvala, in my case I am using a SurfaceView

Comment: Tash Pemhiwa: You probably want to start a new question, with more detail about your own case, since this one is not yet clarified.

Answer (score 0):

I experience this same problem - this is because the default camera sensor orientation may be either 90 degrees or 270 degrees depending on your device. In order to render the camera output to the screen, there is a fair bit of pre-processing involved in setting up the camera outputs.

The method setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) in the official Google example shows how to do this(https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java). Basically, it checks the camera's sensor orientation and figures out if the preview area needs to be rotated.